# Security exception while calling bindAppWidgetId

Tags: android, android-widget, homescreen, launcher

While developing a Launcher (Homescreen) application for Android, I've come into a security exception I don't understand.

- When calling the
  [bindAppWidgetId()][1] method from
  within my Launcher Activity, I get
  this security exception :

08-19 11:30:11.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6032): java.lang.SecurityException: bindGagetId appWidgetId=99 provider=ComponentInfo{com.android.music/com.android.music.MediaAppWidgetProvider}: **User 10034 does not have android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET.**

I first thought I had forgotten the BIND_APPWIDGET permission in my manifest, but it is definitely there.

The android api documentation states this :

> "You need the APPWIDGET_LIST
>   permission. This method is to be used
>   by the AppWidget picker."

I tried to add the permission android.permission.APPWIDGET_LIST, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Also, I've looked at the manifest of the Settings application from the android sources that contains the AppWidgetPickActivity code : there's a special line that asks to share user id :

> "android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"

Could it be related to my problem ?

If anyone has an idea that would be great !

Cheers, 
Laurent

Comment: This a way from : [A solution is here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746173/adding-widgets-to-a-launcher-page-without-bindappwidgetid/9784376

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found an answer!

**BindAppWidgetId() is deliberately not available to applications! (security problems).**

> "The android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET
>   permission is a system permission. **You
>   can only get that permission if your
>   package is installed as a system
>   package** (installed in /system/app in
>   stead of /data/app) or sign you app
>   with a certificate that's the same as
>   your android image. So basicly this
>   means you can only use this permission
>   if you are also the creator of the
>   android image on your platform/phone."

Here are the links to this information :

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/231245ba6d1e690f/047b9d3f776d7e54?lnk=gst&q=bindAppWidgetId#047b9d3f776d7e54

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f24e0f484a79d529/ef84188e8533a125?lnk=gst&q=bindAppWidgetId#ef84188e8533a125

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search reveals that `android.permission.APPWIDGET_LIST` is a usable permission, even though it's not listed in the API docs.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but I had already added this one in my Manifest.

Alas it doesn't solve my security issue ... the problem remains.

Comment: By the way, could you cite the sources that state it's a usable permission ?

Comment: Absolutely: http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/open-gesture-pro_ktz.html

Sorry for the late response.

Comment: in the Permissions tab, it lists android.permission.APPWIDGET_LIST.