# Unable to build AppwidgetHost or Appwiget for Android TV

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, android-tv

```
List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> infos = mAppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders();
int widgetId = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(infos.get(0).provider)[0];
```

Above code throws below security exception

> java.lang.SecurityException: Package  does not belong to 10069

Alternatively, if I launch the appwidgetpicker using action [ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND) to retrieve the user permission,

> ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_PICK

again above exception(**Only on android TV**) is thrown:

However same code works on mobile, but not on android TV, so *how do we build [appwidgethost](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/host) for android TV*?

**UPDATE 1:**
Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582588/2700586) also still throws same exception

**UPDATE 2:**
Found [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37043106) on Android TV for the same

Answer (score 0):

ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK and ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND are not available in AndroidTV.
The only way to allow your app to use widget is to use **adb shell** and execute

```
appwidget grantbind --package <your_package_name> --user 0
```

It is half solution, your users should have enough knowledge to be able to set up adb and run shell commands.

So what I'm doing in my application:

1. I'm using custom widget picker dialog.
2. When user picks a widget I check if ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND is
   awailable
3. If it is not I'm trying to use reflection to grant binding
4. If reflection does not work I'm checking if there is su (root)
   available
5. If it's not rooted I'm displaying a dialog explaining how to enable
   widgets manually via adb.

Not's not perfect but at least something.

Comment: BTW If you are system developer then you can just make your application system and add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_APPWIDGET_BIND_PERMISSIONS"/> to manifest.